# ShellExecute brings Office programs to crash

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I used to printout PDF-files from MS Access 2010 32-bit on Windows 7 32 bit with this code.

```
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String) As Long

Function PrintAttachement() 
ShellExecute 0, "print", "\\s1016d\attachments\40297827.pdf", "", ""

End Function
```

Now, we changed to Windows 7 64 bit, but still Office 32 bit and ALL Office applications crashes when running this function.

Strange, because if I use "open" iso. "print" it works as expected!

Please help, as I am lost how to correct my function to run again.

All I want is to printout a PDF-File from Access without opening the file.
As there are many files in a row, I cannot open any PDF-app to printout the file.

Thanks
Michael

Edit: After Long searches I found the solution!

You have to declare the function like in 64bit application, but to make shure to run it also on machines with 32bit declare both.

```
#If VBA7 Then

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As Long

#Else

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As Long

#End If
```

Comment: If you found the solution, please add it as an answer down below.  You can accept it as solving the problem also.  Both actions help the community and specifically those of us looking for unanswered questions.

Comment: I would do this, but I am not able to insert a comment into this answering box as I always get " too many characters..."

Comment: Add an answer (not a comment).  It's down in the giant text box below.  It says `Your Answer` and has a header with buttons like a formatting toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to show this as answered, and also vouch that this does solve the same situation for me.  If you are referencing a windows DLL in-line, you need to ensure that the correct DLL is being used based on the environment the access DB is being used in (32bit vs 64bit) you can do this dynamically as described above (and repeated here)

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
        Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal lpOperation As String, _
        ByVal lpFile As String, _
        ByVal lpParameters As String, _
        ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
        ByVal nShowCmd As Long _
        ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
        Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal lpOperation As String, _
        ByVal lpFile As String, _
        ByVal lpParameters As String, _
        ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
        ByVal nShowCmd As Long _
        ) As Long
#End If
```